# Why does my node.js HTTP request fail with code 501?

Tags: node.js, docker

I have been trying to call a web service running in Docker on my machine on port 4801. I can access the service in the browser, via curl and via .NET's `HttpClient`, but if I try from node.js (either using `axios` or the native `http` module) the request fails with status code 501 Not Implemented.

I eventually tracked the problem down to the fact that there is another process, called `ServiceLayer.exe` (description: "Logitech VC ServiceLayer"), listening on port 4801. How is Docker able to expose my service on that port such that it can be accessed by the methods listed above, but not from node?

Here is a minimal repro:

```js
const axios = require("axios");

axios.get("http://localhost:4801")
  .then(response => console.log(response.data))
  .catch(error => console.log({
    status: error.response.status,
    headers: error.response.headers
  }));
```

```sh
docker run -p 4801:8000 -d crccheck/hello-world
node test.js
```

Output:

```
{
  status: 501,
  headers: { server: 'websocket-sharp/1.0', connection: 'close' }
}
```

I am guessing the `websocket-sharp` bit is potentially significant.

Comment: If the crash occurs because the `4801` is in use, there are two ways to do it. First, Kill a process in use, take that port, and give it a new port with `kill -9 <_pid>` command. Second, give a new port such as `4802` instead of `4801`.

Comment: When I run the code you gave me, I run without any problems.

Comment: I've solved my issue by assigning a different port to my service, so my question is now for interest only. Why does node fail where other applications/frameworks succeed?

Comment: What exactly is the curl command you entered?

Comment: `curl http://localhost:4801`